# Popularize high priority initiative with senior folks from other departments

Tags: management, project-management

If I wish to popularize a high priority initiative of my department with senior folks from other departments, then what should I do? My manager is not keen on me reaching out and holding meetings with seniors from other divisions, but their buy-in is necessary for my work to succeed. What's the best way?

Comment: Who has determined that this initiative is "high priority"?

Comment: What kind of buy in do you need? How does your manager want to get the buy in?

Answer (score 5):

> My manager is not keen on me reaching out and holding meetings with seniors from other divisions

Then, follow your manager's direction: Don't reach out and hold those meetings.

Your manager may have many good reasons for giving that direction. You can ask him why if you wish. I am sure he will give you some good reasons.

For example, sometimes, different divisions have different priorities that may not be in sync with your division. Other divisions may have too many other urgent/critical tasks to solve, and don't have time to meet with you.

Normally, reaching out to other teams and departments within your own division may not always be an easy task.

Now, you want to reach to other divisions, which is probably far from your and your manager's daily tasks.